# Deploying GWT App with RPC calls on Apache

Tags: gwt, apache2, axis, gwt-rpc

I'm developing a `GWT` app, let's say `SoapCon` that connects to a web service so I'm using `Axis` on my server-side to connect to this web service. When I run my app in development mode, it works fine (which returns xml as its response). But when I deployed my app to `Apache 2.0` in `Linux`, RPC failed and returns `404` for the servlet mapping URL.

When I deployed this app to `Apache`, I recursively copied the /war/soapcon to the /var/www/html/SoapCon directory and the SoapCon.html and .css.

Here's my `web.xml`:

```
<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sample.google.server.SampleServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/soapcon/greet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

SoapCon.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='soapcon'>
....
```

The client side stub for the RPC service:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface SampleService extends RemoteService {
    String method( String params, ... );
}
```

When I run my app

#### http://localhost/SoapCon/SoapCon.html

the module is loaded but when I clicked a button which will call RPC method from my server, error occurs returning:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
  <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /SoapCon/soapcon/greet was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

What should I do? please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are running tomcat on your apache server. To deploy your gwt project you should [build a .war-file](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/), and do not try to copy all parts manually.

The 404 error tells us, that the URL "/SoapCon/soapcon/greet" was not found / in the right place on your server. Deploying the .war instead of manual copying will automatically place everything in the right position.

Comment: hi Erik. i wasn't running tomcat in my apache server.

Comment: @rajec: so you are trying to run your gwt-project as CGI on the server-side?